# Hibernate exception :org.hibernate.HibernateException: Flush during cascade is dangerous

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

I am getting org.hibernate.HibernateException: Flush during cascade is dangerous this exception when I tried to update the db using many threads in parallel. My scenario is this : I want to copy data from one table to another and using threads in parallel so that each thread will copy a single row to another table and update a flag to indicate it is copied.

this is my code :

```
 private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);

    public void startThreads() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            executor.submit(new Spinach(i));
        }
    }
```

And, inside the Spinach class call method, I have this code :

```
Transaction t1=sessionFirstDb.beginTransaction();
Transaction t2 = sessionSecondDb.beginTransaction();
//setting the POJO values
sessionSecondDb.save(user);
t2.commit();
a.setIsCopyDone("yes");
sessionFirstDb.saveOrUpdate(a);
t1.commit();
```

And, the exception is

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Flush during cascade is dangerous
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1023)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
```

And, I went through this link :
[HibernateException: Flush during cascade is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650940/hibernateexception-flush-during-cascade-is-dangerous) but the suggested solution is to use a single thread.

Comment: Okay I have two stupid questions: 1) Why do you need two transactions here? 2) What happens if you put "Transaction t1=sessionFirstDb.beginTransaction();
" just before the a.setIsCopy... method ?

Comment: I am connecting to two dbs so two transactions.And, changing the position of transaction does not make any difference.

Comment: Is it that your Hibernate session is accessed concurrently by two threads? If this is true, you must know that a Session is not thread-safe. Copying one row from one table to another sounds like hacking. You can do it with native query inside a single transaction bound to a given thread. If you want to run this concurrently then you'd better use a thread pool executor and each worker thread would start it's own transaction. But you need to make sure the worker threads are coordinated by a master thread so that they don't operate on the same rows.

Comment: Hi @Vlad , Am using a thread pool executor only and sorry I forgot to add that code. Added it now.Each worker thread starts its own transaction and I have a flag which tells which row to access but I am not sure about the master thread concept.

Comment: Ok, but why do you need two transactions in the first place? You could have one transaction which takes one row from the table and moves it to the other. The master thread would be the one that sends job requests to the worker. It can for example extract a batch of 1000 rows to process, and since you have 50 workers, it will split those 1000 ids into 50 chunks. Each worker will get a chunk to process, hence there will be no overlap. The master could call: executorService.invokeAll and iterate the Future list for calling the future.get() method. When all workers are done, the master can proceed

Comment: @VladMihalcea Two transactions because two dbs are involved. And, Should each of the worker thread do a commit? If I try that, I end up getting the same exception. Without commit , the data is not reflected in db.