# HibernateException while executing transactions concurrently

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have this simple method:

```
  public void addPerson(Person person) {

    EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
    try {
      transaction.begin();
      em.persist(person);
      transaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("Exception occurred: ",e);
    }
  }
```

When this method is called from multiple threads concurrently, i get this exception:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Flush during cascade is dangerous
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:65)
        ... 35 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Flush during cascade is dangerous
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1449)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:511)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3290)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2486)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:178)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:39)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:271)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104)
        ... 34 more
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HibernateException: Flush during cascade is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650940/hibernateexception-flush-during-cascade-is-dangerous)

Comment: Yes it's similar but there wasn't any good solution mentioned. I have accepted an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, both of your threads are sharing the same Hibernate Session.
And it is clearly mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html) of the Session class that

> It is **not intended** that implementors be threadsafe. Instead each
> thread/transaction should obtain its own instance from a
> SessionFactory.

Thus for each thread, you need to do something like:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

Then begin and commit your transaction and lastly remember to **close** the session:

```
session.beginTransaction();
//Do something
session.getTransaction().commit();
```